# tfs2010 teambuild overnight unit tests have stopped completing (due to assertion fail?)

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, tfsbuild

The auto build completes (when 'Disable Tests' is set to true in build definition) but when I enable tests the build doesn't complete.
I'm building as Debug/AnyCpu. I've copy-and-pasted the MSTest line and ran it in a shell on the build server and I got some assertion fails. Thus, I think the server's waiting for a response to ignore/retry these assertions, does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to using assertions during your unit testing, I would recommend using the Unit Test Framework Assert class instead of Debug.Assert.

See this method for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.fail.aspx

You have different ways to assert (AreEqual, AreNotEqual, IsTrue, etc.).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unit test using a release build on your server - it won't have any asserts in it.

Comment: In that case you could use an assert class that doesn't stall your program by opening a dialog box.

Comment: cheers, have switched to: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean build doesn't complete? The build log will tell you what is the most recent action. You might want to set the logging level to detailed for the build to see more information. Also one issue might be that you have configured the build to fail if tests fail. In that case you could add Ignore attribute into those tests:

```
[TestMethod]
[Ignore]
public void TestMethodThatFails()
```

Of course you should fix those tests rather than ignore them but that is not the subject of this question.

Comment: one of the tests caused an assertion fail in the code (which stalled the overnight testing; thus I didn't know if the other 50 odd tests had worked or not), so as per Duat Le's comment I switched from System.Diagnostics.Assert to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert and it now completes giving the relevant info